# DNS: Zone file for experimental / private RR Type

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I'm experimenting with a new RR Type for DNS records.  The DNS standard allows this, as long as you use a RR TYPE in the range 65,xxx.  Dig supports this, by specifying type to be TYPE65xxxx.  But I can't figure out how to have Bind parse and serve a zone file with an unknown type.

I'd like to use a format similar to what dig does when it encounters it: I'll specify the type number (eg TYPE65333) the length of the RDATA (eg 32) and the RDATA hexdump.  How can I get BIND to parse and serve rthis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIND will accept records of arbitrary type on the standardized [generic opaque record format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3597):

```
foo.example.com. IN TYPE<typeno> \# <length> <hexencodedRData>
```